# Matlab 'heatmap' with scatterplot data

Tags: matlab

Sorry if this question has been answered elsewhere but I'm having trouble finding a solution...

I have `scatterplot` data, `x` and `y`, and colour data `c` (all of which are vectors).

```
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
c = rand(100,1)*50;
scatter(x,y,c,'fill')
```

[image]

However, I'd like to display this as a 'heapmap', so that instead of `c` being the size, it would represent the intensity and it sort of looks like this:
[image]

I don't want to use `surf` and would like to to be 2D like this. Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the surface plot you want, you'll need to interpolate over the [0,1] area. Using "scatteredInterpolant" works pretty well for this.

```
N = 1000;
[Xi,Yi] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,N),linspace(0,1,N));
SI = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,c);
Ci = SI(Xi,Yi);
imagesc(Ci);
```

The result doesn't look too smooth with only 100 random points, but I think it's what you are looking for!
[image]

Comment: This also extrapolates for cases, where there is not data. Look at the bottom right and left corners as example. In order to prevent extrapolation and only allow interpolation, I would suggest to use ``Ci = griddata(x, y, c, Xi, Yi);``. However, in the question clearly a completely filled area is wanted, so it matches the question perfectly. To keep axis scale according to your data, the plot-part would read ``imagesc(linspace(0,1,N), linspace(0,1,N), Ci)``. Other than that: definitely a good way.