# Matlab Help: How to make a Heatmap with nonuniform matrix data?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, heatmap, scatter-plot

I want to make a heatmap of data parameter Z vs. time (x-axis) and depth (y) where the quantity Z corresponds to color.

To the best of my knowledge pcolor won't work because my actual data can't be sorted into a uniform matrix that would make logical sense (i.e. at a certain time I might have 10 data points or 6, etc.), so I tried an approach with a scatterplot as I'll basically be working with single column matrices.

So, I was able to make a scatterplot via

```
sz = 10;
scatter(all_dates,all_depth,sz,example_data,'filled')
```

where all_dates, all_depth, and exampe_data are all 10,000x1 arrays and all_dates are in this format ('11-May-2023 16:18:00').

I'm able to generate this attached figure. [Scatterplot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAeLl.png) However, I'd like it to look like a heatmap with interpolation between all the points.

I've looked up other examples and it seems like the matlab function Scatterinterpolant would be useful and I start to get into trouble here.

It throws up errors because it doesn't like the dates because it isn't a double array. So I tried converting it to a numeric form and am able to successfully run

```
D = convertTo(all_dates,'excel');
F = scatteredInterpolant(D,all_depth,example_data);
```

And I'm really stuck on how to plot this. I saw [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956462/matlab-heatmap-with-scatterplot-data) and tried applying it but

```
[Xi,Yi] = meshgrid(D,all_depth);
Ci = F(Xi,Yi);
imagesc(Ci);
```

gets me some ridiculous 10,000 x 10,000 figure [ridiculous figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZNUq.jpg)that makes no sense. Something is definitely off and I'm guessing it's with interpolating over meshgrid. Also, not sure how to convert back or display this as a plot so I can display the proper date information.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Does not seem wrong at a glance. It will be useful if you add a fully working example.

Comment: That’s not how `meshgrid` works. Just look at it’s output. You want to use `x=linspace(0,1,1000)`, or similar, as input. Pick you smallest and largest value along each axis, and create 1000 points in between. That is the basis for your grid on which you resample your data.

Comment: Thanks so much @CrisLuengo! This was exactly the fix I needed. Also for anyone that comes on this thread, you would need to convert your data back using the datetime function (for me `code` datetime(yourdata,convertfrom,'excel'). Then you can plot using pcolor easily!